# How do I make the frame and buttons on the screen change dynamically when resizing the window in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
FreamBtn = Frame(wind, bg="gray26", height=50, width=1090)
FreamBtn.place(x=20, y=170)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `pack()` method: `FrameBtn.pack(expand="yes", fill="both")`. This should make it expand and shrink with the window.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I want to put it in a specific place

Comment: @ABODEALBASH I looked in the documentation and there's no real way to make the frame fit inside the window *and* have it in a specific place just by using the `place()` function. The only parameters that you can pass to `place()` either set the anchor of the frame (what you're already doing), adjust the border mode, or set the width and height of the frame relative to the window.

Comment: With that in mind, you *could* maybe adjust the size of the widget whenever the window is resized, by binding to the window's `<Configure>` event. I'll update my answer if I can find a good way to do that.

Comment: Okay, tried the method mentioned above and it works fine if the frame has nothing in it, but when I put a button into the frame, it wouldn't resize. You can look in the revision history to see the way that worked with an empty frame, if you like.